# Reading Lists in python 3.0 using for loop and append instead of input().split() , using append cause some unknown error

Tags: python, list, python-3.x

Why can't I use:

```
somelist = []
for a in (0, 5):
    x = input()
    somelist.append(x)
```

Instead of:

```
somelist = [int(x) for x in input().split()]
```

I always run into unknown error while trying 1st code block !

Comment: Firstly, you have indentation Error.  Secondly, it should be `for a in range(0,5):` instead of `for a in (0,5):`. `range` returns a list in `python2` and a `range` object in python3, both of them is iterable, so you can iterate over them as per your use case.

Comment: Don't you think posting the error would be a good idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your list comprehension is not even doing the same thing as your loop is supposed to do, but that aside, the problem in your loop is that you are calling `for a in (0,5)` instead of `range(5)` (that is, if you want to ask for user input five times). Also your loop is not properly intended. `for a in (0,5)` actually just goes through the numbers 0 and 5 and then ends.

The proper loop would look like this:

```
somelist = []
for a in range(5):
    somelist.append(input())
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
some_list = []

for a in range(5):
    x = input()
    some_list.append(x)
```

**Output:**

```
>>> some_list = []
>>>
>>> for a in range(5):
...     x = input()
...     some_list.append(x)
...
2
3
4
5
6
>>> some_list
[2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```